# How to update plot ranges (x_range/y_range)?

Tags: python, plot, range, bokeh

I am making a bubble chart using Bokeh and I'd like to be able to update my plot's x_range, as it can be used for either integers or strings.

If I'm not mistaken, Int ranges will be managed through `Range1d` and string ones through `FactorRange`.

I'm trying to do it using the update() function, called whenever a control is used:

```
plot = figure(y_range=FactorRange(factors=pandata['HostnameIP'].tolist()), plot_height=600, plot_width=700, title="Visualization", toolbar_location="above", tools=[hover, BoxSelectTool(), ResetTool()])
plot.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source, size=7, color="color", line_color=None, fill_alpha="alpha")

controls = [malware, compromise, x_axis]
for control in controls:
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())

def update():
    df = select_units()
    x_name = axis_map[x_axis.value]

    plot.xaxis.axis_label = x_axis.value

    if x_name == 'Malware':
        plot.x_range=FactorRange(factors=pandata['Malware'].tolist())
        l.children[0].children[1] = plot

# [...]

inputs = widgetbox(*controls, sizing_mode=sizing_mode)
l = layout([
    [inputs, plot],
    [data_table]
], sizing_mode=sizing_mode)

update()

curdoc().add_root(l)
curdoc().title = "Visualization"
```

According to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982276/how-to-refresh-bokeh-document), this technique should be working, but I'm getting a blank plot instead.

I've also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29294958), but it looks like figure.set() doesn't exist anymore.

Any ideas on how to do that? I'm still discovering Bokeh.

TYA :)

Comment: Could you provide a minimum working example?

Comment: Also let's check foundations: are you running `bokeh serve` on this script? You can't generally run Bokeh server apps by executing `python app.py` you have to run it using the Bokeh server e.g. `bokeh serve app.py`